# How to access for each loop html properties to code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm trying to access these data in code behind file. if i change these html tag to asp tags i cannot retrieve data from for each loop. here i want actual sales price and the product size which are generated by for each loop to save these properties in database. So is there any possible ways to solve these problem??

**aspx page**

```
        <%
                foreach (Com.Idk.Application.ImaraResPOS.Entities.ProductSize psize in psList)
                    { 
                %>
                <div class="col-sm-12  text-center type">

                    <div class="circle bg">
                        <img src="images/Meal-100.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-align-size">

                        <button class="btn btn-primary ladda-button cd-add-to-cart" data-price="<%=psize.SalesPrice %>" data-name="<%= psize.SizeDef.Name %>" data-product-image="images/3.jpg" data-style="expand-right" id="Breadtype_btn" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bread_type">
                            <%= psize.SizeDef.Name %>
                            <img src="images/Buy-30.png" style="height: 30px; width: 30px">
                            <h3 class="hide">
                                <%= psize.Id%>
                            </h3>

                        </button>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <%

                    }

                %>
```

**code behind**

```
 private void InsertProductSizeToSale()
    {
          string sizeID = Request.QueryString["size_id"].ToString();

        Com.Idk.Application.ImaraResPOS.Entities.ProductSize prid = new Com.Idk.Application.ImaraResPOS.Entities.ProductSize();

        psList.Select(Global.sess, "ProductSize","where Product_ID="+ prid);
        if (psList.Count > 0)
        {

            Hashtable parameterList = new Hashtable();
            OfferDetailList odList = new OfferDetailList();


            parameterList.Clear();
            parameterList.Add("productSizeId", sizeID );
            parameterList.Add("comboId", null);

            parameterList.Add("currentDate", DateTimeUtil.GetFormattedString(((Sale)index.saleid).Date));

            parameterList.Add("currentTime", DateTimeUtil.GetFormatedTimeString(DateTime.Now));
            parameterList.Add("day", Const.GetDay(((Sale)index.saleid).Date.DayOfWeek));
            odList.SelectUsingSP(Global.sess, "SqlProGetOfferDetail", parameterList);

            if (odList.Count == 0)
            {
               //want to retrive psize properties here
               // here i'm getting an error

               SqlProInsertProductSizeToSale(prid, sizeID, psize.SalesPrice, psize.SalesPrice);
            }
            else if (odList.Count > 0)
            {  SqlProInsertProductSizeToSale(selectedProduct, selectedProductSize, odSelection.GetSelectedProductSizePrice(), selectedProductSize.SalesPrice);
             }

            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to get the values from the aspx page itself?  Why can't you just get them from `Com.Idk.Application.ImaraResPOS.Entities`?

Comment: its an entity class object to access attributes

Comment: its already developed in pos system am using that object to retrieve data

Comment: Exactly.  So use it to retrieve data.  Once you have retrieved it, pass the data into `SqlProInsertProductSizeToSale` to save it.

Comment: yes. i'm trying to get actual product size, sales price which are generated in for each loop. here if i change this '<%= psize.Id%>' code i cannot access the loop

Comment: if i add runat server to this h3 tag it doesn't work!!  @jo

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you wish to get the data from the page.  Since you are populating the page from some entity objects, why not just get the data from the entity objects directly?

**Codebehind**

```
foreach (Com.Idk.Application.ImaraResPOS.Entities.ProductSize p in psList)
{ 
    SqlProInsertProductSizeToSale(p.prid, p.sizeID, p.SalesPrice, p.SalesPrice);
}
```